# Why I dont see a msg from message queue?

Tags: c, unix, queue, message-queue

I would like to understand how message queues in Unix work. I wrote a simple code which sends a short message to queue and then I can read that message. But my code shows :

[image]

And I dont know why - and I cant see a message I send to queue. Heres my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct mymsgbuf {
    long mtype;
    char mtext[1024];
}msg;

int send_message(int qid, struct mymsgbuf *buffer )
{
    int result = -1, length = 0;
    length = sizeof(struct mymsgbuf) - sizeof(long);
    if((result = msgsnd(qid, buffer, length, 0)) == -1)
        return -1;
    return result;
}

int read_message(int qid, long type, struct mymsgbuf *buffer)
{
    int result, length;
    length = sizeof(struct mymsgbuf) - sizeof(long);
    if((result = msgrcv(qid, buffer, length, type,  0)) == -1)
        return -1;
    printf("Type: %ld Text: %s\n", buffer->mtype, buffer->mtext);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int buffsize = 1024;

    int qid = msgget(ftok(".", 0), IPC_CREAT | O_EXCL);
    if (qid == -1)
    {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(1);
    }

    msg.mtype = 1;
    strcpy(msg.mtext, "my simple msg");

    if((send_message(qid, &msg)) == -1)
    {
        perror("msgsnd");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((read_message(qid, 1, &msg) == -1))
    {
        perror("msgrcv");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I changed a line with msgget for this line:

```
int qid = msgget(ftok(".", 0), IPC_CREAT | O_EXCL | 0600);
```

it shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`msgget`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgget.html):

> The low-order 9 bits of msg_perm.mode shall be set equal to the low-order 9 bits of msgflg.

You need to add some permissions to your queue, at least read and write. Do something like:

```
int qid = msgget(ftok(".", 0), IPC_CREAT | O_EXCL | 0600);
```

Comment: Make sure you remove the existing queue before re-running your app (`ipcs -q` to list, `ipcrm -q <queue id>` to clean)

Comment: unfortunately, same result :( - msgget: Permission denided

Comment: What OS are you using? Make really sure you delete that queue. If you ever ran that code as another user (esp. as root), you might not have deleted the right queue.

Comment: I use Kubuntu 12.04 LTS. I've never run this code as root, just only as myself. When I deleted the queue (there were no queue, Im sure, checked it) run my code once again, got message `msgget: Permission denided` its quite strange, this SHOULD work, huh?

Comment: Yes, works for me on Linux. Try changing the first `ftok` parameter (to `/tmp` for example).

Comment: Well, if that worked, it means you **do** have a message queue with the old key generated with `ftok(".",0)` :-) (A reboot will fix, but `ipcs -q` as root should show it too if it's hiding.)